# How to select text with the mouse without going into insert mode

Tags: vim

I used to be able to select text with my mouse in Vim, and then hit <kbd>x</kbd> to cut it. Now, when I do that, it does cut the text to my clipboard like before, but it also inserts a single `x` character at the point of cutting, which did not occur in the past. It seems like selecting text with the mouse puts me into insert mode, so that my subsequent hitting of <kbd>x</kbd> does cut the text to my clipboard, but also inserts a single `x` ASCII character.

I recently changed my machine, and thus lost my _vimrc (Windows) file. I probably had some key remapping in my old _vimrc to accomplish what I want, but no longer have access to that file.

Something similar happens if I select text with my mouse and hit <kbd>d</kbd>. The text is cut to my clipboard, and a single `d` character is inserted, and I am in text insert mode.

Does anyone know what line to add to my _vimrc (.vimrc) to create the behavior so that when I select multiple lines of text with my mouse and hit <kbd>x</kbd>, it will cut the text to my clipboard, not insert any text in place, and leave me in command mode?

My `mouse` setting is set to `mouse=a`.

Comment: Thank you to the Tin Man for your edits of my request for readability. I will try to consider your edits in any future request/question I post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called "select mode". From `:h Select-mode`:

```
8. Select mode                      *Select* *Select-mode*

Select mode looks like Visual mode, but the commands accepted are quite
different.  This resembles the selection mode in Microsoft Windows.
When the 'showmode' option is set, "-- SELECT --" is shown in the last line.

Entering Select mode:
- Using the mouse to select an area, and 'selectmode' contains "mouse".
  'mouse' must also contain a flag for the current mode.
- Using a non-printable movement command, with the Shift key pressed, and
  'selectmode' contains "key".  For example: <S-Left> and <S-End>.  'keymodel'
  must also contain "startsel".
- Using "v", "V" or CTRL-V command, and 'selectmode' contains "cmd".
- Using "gh", "gH" or "g_CTRL-H" command in Normal mode.
- From Visual mode, press CTRL-G.           *v_CTRL-G*
```

The reasoning behind this mode existing can be found in "[What is the select mode and when is it relevant to use it?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4891/what-is-the-select-mode-and-when-is-it-relevant-to-use-it)".

To disable select mode being entered from selecting something with your mouse, add

```
set selectmode=
```

to your `.vimrc`

Comment: Thank you DJMcMayhem for the detailed answer, and for pointing toward the in-Vim help so that I can find this information for myself in the future. Your suggestion solved my problem.